# How to prove the set of all symmetric matrices with eigenvalues in $(0,2)$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, connectedness, symmetric-matrices

> Prove that space $X$ of all symmetric matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ with both the eigenvalues belonging to the interval $(0,2),$ with the topology inherited from $M_2(\mathbb R)  $ is **connected**.

Space of all symmetric matrices in $M_2(\mathbb R)$ is path -connected.

I was not able to show why $det(\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B)\neq 0$ where $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $A,B\in GL_2(\mathbb R), A=A^T,B=B^T.$

Also how to use the eigenvalues from $(0,2)$ to prove the connectedness.

I hope my doubts are clear to you.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The space $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$ is connected. Now let$$\Lambda=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in(0,2)\right\}.$$The set $\Lambda$ is connected too. So, the range of the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}SO_2(\mathbb{R})\times\Lambda&\longrightarrow&GL_2(\mathbb{R})\\(P,D)&\mapsto&P^{-1}DP\end{array}$$is connected too. But this range is $X$.

Comment: I had another question too: whether $det(\lambda A+(1-\lambda ) B)$ equal to $0$ or not? where $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $A,B$ are symmetric matrices with determinant non-zero.

Comment: Yes, it **can** be $0$. Suppose that $A=\operatorname{Id}$, the $B=-\operatorname{Id}$, and that $\lambda=\frac12$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos What is $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$ here. I'm sorry if this is a trivial question but I am unaware of this notation.

Comment: The space $SO_n(\Bbb R)$ is the space of those $n\times n$ matrices $A$ such that $A^TA=\operatorname{Id}$ and that $\det A=1$. It turns out that$$SO_2(\Bbb R)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,\theta\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$

Comment: Why the modal matrix is in $\ SO_2(R)$ and not in $O_2(R)$,i.e. the set of all orthogonal matrices? Being a symmetric matric the matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable. So the determinant of the modal matrix can be both +1 and -1. Why is it always +1?

Comment: @Megha What does “modal matrix” mean?

Answer (score 1):

One-line proof: every $A\in X$ is path-connected to $I$ by the line segment $\{tA+(1-t)I: 0\leq t\leq 1\}\subseteq X$.

Your original approach also works. Let $A,B\in X$ and $0\leq t\leq 1$. Then $A,B$ and in turn $tA+(1-t)B$ are positive definite and hence all eigenvalues of $tA+(1-t)B$ are positive. Also,
$$
\|tA+(1-t)B\|_2
\leq t\|A\|_2+(1-t)\|B\|_2
< 2t+2(1-t)=2.
$$
Therefore all eigenvalues of $tA+(1-t)B$ lie inside the interval $(0,2)$. Consequently, $X$ is path-connected because $\{tA+(1-t)B: 0\leq t\leq 1\}\subseteq X$ for any $A,B\in X$.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove much more (in $S_n(\mathbb{R})$ , the set of $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices).

$\textbf{Proposition 1}$. The set $Z_I=\{A\in S_n(\mathbb{R});spectrum(A)\subset I\}$ is convex (where $I$ is some interval of $\mathbb{R}$).

$\textbf{Proof}$. We use the fact that if $A\in S_n(\mathbb{R})$, then $\sup_{||x||_2=1}x^TAx=\sup(spectrum(A)),\inf_{||x||_2=1}x^TAx=\inf(spectrum(A))$.

Then $\lambda x^TAx+(1-\lambda)x^TBx\in I$ when $A,B\in Z_I,||x||_2=1,\lambda\in [0,1]$. $\square$

$\textbf{Proposition 2}$. If $I=[a,b],a<b$, then $Z_I$ is homeomorphic to the compact ball $B_{n(n+1)/2}$.

$\textbf{Proof}.$ $Z_I$ is also closed (the eigenvalues are continuous functions of the entries) and bounded ($||A||_2=\sup_{\lambda\in spectrum(A)}(|\lambda|))$.

Finally, $Z_I$ is convex compact and, therefore, homeomorphic to the compact ball in $\mathbb{R}^k$, where $k$ is the number of degrees of freedom of $S_n(\mathbb{R})$.